# Can you properly test a const member function If you include exception safety inside that function without having to comment it out after?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, exception, constants

**Question**
How does one test a const member function?

### Goal:

Unit test a const subscript operator and get a passing test. In other words can I **avoid** writing a test; have a compiler throw an error to prove success, then **avoid** the need to comment the test out to allow proper compilation for the remainder of the tests?

**My Attempts:**
My reasoning was if I test for **is_const<>::value** and is true I can throw an exception that would be caught by my unit test and allow the test to "Pass" do to failure to change value of element at location of subscript index.

**my const subscript definition**

```cpp
   #include <type_traits>

   // operator [] const
    
    template <typename T>                               
    typename Vector<T>::const_reference
    Vector<T>::operator[](size_t index) const {
        if (size_ <= index || index < 0) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range.");
        }
        if constexpr(std::is_const<std::decltype(*this)>::value) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Cannot modify elements of a const Vector.");
        }
        return array_[index];
    }
```

**my UnitTest**

```cpp
TEST(SubScriptConst) {
    const Vector<int> myVecConst = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    try {
        myVecConst[2] = 4; // This will throw an exception?
    } 
    catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cout << "SUCCESS | Caught exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    CHECK_EQUAL(myVecConst[2], 2);
}
```

**The obvious.**
It does not work. I know its because of my lack of understanding the language. My assumptions are the compiler is checking the value assignment of a const before the code is executed and gives error. If I am able to I will be placing the try block inside a MACRO #ifdef for testing only and still allow the compiler to throw error when not testing.

Comment: What is your basis for thinking that attempting to modify a `const` object is a runtime error, not a compile time error?

Comment: there was no basis. I honestly wasn't distinguishing between the two until I read your comment. This is obviously a compile time error. Thank you for that sanity check. So it is safe to say NO, there is no other way beside how I have been writing it and the exception handling specifically regarding the type evaluation is pointless?

Comment: Right now I'm stuck not understanding what you think is happening with your "exception safety". Of course the object on whom a const member function is being called is const. Why would you throw an exception there at all?

Comment: because I am learning and had not been that logical about it until you pointed it out! If there is anything else I have overlooked and you'd be so kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a class member function declered as `const` then it can't modify any class data members except the class data members which are declered `mutable`.

This `const` behavior is enforced by compiler and not the C++ runtime. So if someone will try to modify a non-mutable data member in `const` member function then it will be a compile time error and not a runtime error. So you can skip writing such test cases.

Following are some related excerpts from in C++ standard:

> [*Note 1*: Thus in a `const` member function, the object for which the function is called is accessed through a `const`
> access path. *—end note*]

> `int s::f() const { return a; }`
>
> The **`a++`** in the body of **`s::h`** is ill-formed because it tries to modify (a part of) the object for which **`s::h()`** is called.
>
> This is not allowed in a **`const`** member function because **`this`** is a pointer to **`const`**; that is, **`*this`** has **`const`** type.